# vernemq status page refuses to connect

Tags: docker-compose, mqtt, metrics, mqtt-vernemq

I'm using the vernemq docker image with a redis docker image. These are my configurations from the docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  redis:
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
    container_name: 'redis_server'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=admin2021
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no
      - REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - 'redis-data:/bitnami/redis/data'
  mqtt_broker:
    image: vernemq/vernemq
    restart: always
    container_name: 'mqtt_broker'
    environment:
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_PLUGINS__VMQ_ACL: 'off'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_PLUGINS__VMQ_PASSWD: 'off'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_PLUGINS__VMQ_DIVERSITY: 'on'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__AUTH_REDIS__ENABLED: 'on'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__REDIS__HOST: redis_server
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__REDIS__PORT: '6379'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__REDIS__PASSWORD: admin2021
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY__REDIS__DATABASE: '0'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ACCEPT_EULA: "yes"
    ports:
      - '1883:1883'
    expose:
      - '1883'
    volumes:
      - ./mqtt/scripts:/etc/scripts
volumes:
  redis-data:
```

I'm not able to access the status page at http://localhost:8888/status as documented here: https://docs.vernemq.com/monitoring/status. I get the error message: This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect. Please explain what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not exposed port `8888`, only `1883` so you it won't be mapped to the container